# How can I prevent emacs from opening a new window for a buffer I already have open in this session?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I typically have two emacs frames open at once.

When I run `vc-diff` a new window is created, regardless of whether a window is displaying that buffer already.

Is there a general way to prevent this occurring?

Comment: It does not do this by default.  Do you have it set up to run `ediff` or some such?

Comment: No, I have nothing in my init file. I am referring to windows in the emacs sense here, not X windows.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `pop-up-frames` to a non-nil value will prevent `pop-to-buffer` from opening a new window.  Instead the `*vc-diff*` buffer will become the active window in the frame that is displaying it.

```
(setq pop-up-frames t)
```

Changing this variable will affect other functions that use `pop-to-buffer` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to customize `display-buffer-base-action` to `display-buffer--other-frame-action` by adding

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(display-buffer-base-action display-buffer--other-frame-action))
```

to your `.emacs.el` or maybe

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(display-buffer-base-action 
   '(display-buffer-reuse-window (reusable-frames . t))))
```

I suggest reading help on all variables (`C-h v`) and functions (`C-h f`) mentioned above.

Good luck!